# Late to sign a work contract, is the commencement date still valid?

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, legal

My commencement is on 01/01/2024, yet I have only signed it today (07/01). I do not know if this is a problem or not, since I have been sent this to sign on 20/12/2023. I have been working this whole time (since this was just a continuation of my previous contract.)

Do the terms not apply for the period I haven't signed this for? Is the contract still valid?

EDIT: This is in UK

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, I don't think so, but it involves a wage increase. I don't know if it now applied to 01/01-07/01

Comment: @PhilipKendall Apologies, its UK

Comment: This is not a legal problem at all. It is a processing problem since 1) you're an existing employee 2) the contract was expected. Seeking "Validity" seems to be playing hardball, so I would just go to HR, apologize for signing it late, and say "Let me know if there are any issues with the contract's original terms."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By far the most likely scenario here is that you're looking for a problem which doesn't exist. Just get the contract back to your HR department ASAP with a little note saying "sorry this is a bit late, hope that won't cause any issues". If your employer is going to try and screw you out of a week's worth of increased wage for that week, you have bigger problems.

As to the legal position: English law (I'm assuming this is England and Wales, rather than Scotland or Northern Ireland which do have separate legal systems) takes the view that if both sides act as if a contract is in place, then the contract is in place even if it wasn't formally signed. Exactly what that means in this case may need a judge to decide, but it sounds to me very much like you'll be fine.